TPM / Install Encrypted
I'm going to be installing 24.04 Nobel Numbat here in a few days. I have a brand new computer ASUS ROG STRIX X670E-F GAMING WIFI / AMD Ryzen™ 9 7950X3D × 32.
I tried with 23.10 and it still asks me for a password to unlock the drive when I boot up so I didn't do something right.
Is there a walkthrough on installing with TPM/Disk encryption somewhere?

This appears to still be a major issue with 24.04. I've reported a bug on Launchpad. Link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision/+bug/2063963
